# Transform DataFrame column of repeated attributes to rows of individual entries and account for sub-table per related element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I read data from a CSV file and put it into a DataFrame. The data contains rows of attributes that are related to an element and need to be transformed to columns instead. For each element, there is also a sub-table that I need to account for.

**Example DataFrame:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["Drop-Down Field Name:", "Test List"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Name:", "Test List"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Type:", "Specific"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Status:", "Active"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Values:", "Text", "Active", "Default", "Weight", "Image"],
                   [None, "DDL V1", "Yes", "Yes", "1.00", None],
                   [None, "DDL V2", "Yes", None, "2.00", None],
                   [None, "DDL V3", "Yes", None, "3.00", None],
                   [None, "DDL V4", "Yes", None, "4.00", None],
                   [None, "DDL V5", "Yes", None, "5.00", None],
                   ["Drop-Down Field Name:", "Test Empty List"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Name:", "Test Empty List"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Type:", "Specific"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Status:", "Active"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Values:", "Text", "Active", "Default", "Weight", "Image"],
                   ["Drop-Down Field Name:", "Email verified?"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Name:", "Yes/No"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Type:", "Reusable"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Status:", "Active"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Values:", "Text", "Active", "Default", "Weight", "Image"],
                   [None, "Yes", "Yes", None, "1.00", "green_checkmark.jpg"],
                   [None, "No", "Yes", None, "0", "red_cross.jpg"],
                   ["Drop-Down Field Name:", "Payment verified?"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Name:", "Yes/No"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Type:", "Reusable"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Status:", "Active"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Values:", "Text", "Active", "Default", "Weight", "Image"],
                   [None, "Yes", "Yes", None, "1.00", "green_checkmark.jpg"],
                   [None, "No", "Yes", None, "0", "red_cross.jpg"],
                   ["Drop-Down Field Name:", "How many years expected from now?"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Name:", "How many years expected from now?"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Type:", "Specific"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Status:", "Active"],
                   ["Drop-Down List Values:", "Text", "Active", "Default", "Weight", "Image"],
                   [None, "One", None, None, None, None],
                   [None, "Two", None, None, None, None],
                   [None, "Three", None, None, None, None],
                   [None, "Four", None, None, None, None],
                   [None, "Five", None, None, None, None],
                   [None, "1", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "2", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "3", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "4", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "5", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "6-10", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "11-15", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "16-20", "Yes", None, None, None],
                   [None, "20+", "Yes", None, None, None]])
```

The sub-tables in the table have their cells in bold. They are not equal in number of entries and can have no entries at all.

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Drop-Down Field Name: | Test List | None | None | None | None |
| 1 | Drop-Down List Name: | Test List | None | None | None | None |
| 2 | Drop-Down List Type: | Specific | None | None | None | None |
| 3 | Drop-Down List Status: | Active | None | None | None | None |
| 4 | Drop-Down List Values: | **Text** | **Active** | **Default** | **Weight** | **Image** |
| 5 | None | **DDL V1** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **1.00** | **None** |
| 6 | None | **DDL V2** | **Yes** | **None** | **2.00** | **None** |
| 7 | None | **DDL V3** | **Yes** | **None** | **3.00** | **None** |
| 8 | None | **DDL V4** | **Yes** | **None** | **4.00** | **None** |
| 9 | None | **DDL V5** | **Yes** | **None** | **5.00** | **None** |
| 10 | Drop-Down Field Name: | Test Empty List | None | None | None | None |
| 11 | Drop-Down List Name: | Test Empty List | None | None | None | None |
| 12 | Drop-Down List Type: | Specific | None | None | None | None |
| 13 | Drop-Down List Status: | Active | None | None | None | None |
| 14 | Drop-Down List Values: | **Text** | **Active** | **Default** | **Weight** | **Image** |
| 15 | Drop-Down Field Name: | Email verified? | None | None | None | None |
| 16 | Drop-Down List Name: | Yes/No | None | None | None | None |
| 17 | Drop-Down List Type: | Reusable | None | None | None | None |
| 18 | Drop-Down List Status: | Active | None | None | None | None |
| 19 | Drop-Down List Values: | **Text** | **Active** | **Default** | **Weight** | **Image** |
| 20 | None | **Yes** | **Yes** | **None** | **1.00** | **green_checkmark.jpg** |
| 21 | None | **No** | **Yes** | **None** | **0** | **red_cross.jpg** |
| 22 | Drop-Down Field Name: | Payment verified? | None | None | None | None |
| 23 | Drop-Down List Name: | Yes/No | None | None | None | None |
| 24 | Drop-Down List Type: | Reusable | None | None | None | None |
| 25 | Drop-Down List Status: | Active | None | None | None | None |
| 26 | Drop-Down List Values: | **Text** | **Active** | **Default** | **Weight** | **Image** |
| 27 | None | **Yes** | **Yes** | **None** | **1.00** | **green_checkmark.jpg** |
| 28 | None | **No** | **Yes** | **None** | **0** | **red_cross.jpg** |
| 29 | Drop-Down Field Name: | How many years expected from now? | None | None | None | None |
| 30 | Drop-Down List Name: | How many years expected from now? | None | None | None | None |
| 31 | Drop-Down List Type: | Specific | None | None | None | None |
| 32 | Drop-Down List Status: | Active | None | None | None | None |
| 33 | Drop-Down List Values: | **Text** | **Active** | **Default** | **Weight** | **Image** |
| 34 | None | **One** | **None** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 35 | None | **Two** | **None** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 36 | None | **Three** | **None** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 37 | None | **Four** | **None** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 38 | None | **Five** | **None** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 39 | None | **1** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 40 | None | **2** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 41 | None | **3** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 42 | None | **4** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 43 | None | **5** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 44 | None | **6-10** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 45 | None | **11-15** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 46 | None | **16-20** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |
| 47 | None | **20+** | **Yes** | **None** | **None** | **None** |

**My Approach:**

1. For each sub-table:

   1. Find start and end locations
   2. Transpose
   3. Replace with the transpose in main table
2. Insert a column that performs `groupby()` and `cumcount()` on element attributes
3. Pivot the table

I am relatively new to pandas, so I'm more than open to hear better approaches :) But here is my code so far:

```
ddlv_locations = df.where(df.eq("Drop-Down List Values:")).stack().index.tolist()
result = df.copy()

# Get sub-table, transpose it, and concatenate with main table
for ddlv_location in ddlv_locations:
    x_start = list(ddlv_location)[0]
    x_end = list(ddlv_location)[0]
    y_start = list(ddlv_location)[1]
    
    # Capture the row index where the sub-table ends
    while(x_end + 1 < df.shape[0] and pd.isna(df.loc[x_end + 1, y_start])):
        x_end = x_end + 1
        
    ddlv = df.loc[x_start:x_end, y_start + 1:df.shape[1]].T     # Transpose the sub-table
    ddlv.columns = range(ddlv.shape[1])     # Reset column index
    
    # Concatenate sub-table into main table whilst removing the original rows for the sub-table
    result = pd.concat([result.loc[:x_start - 1], ddlv]) if x_end == df.shape[0] - 1 else pd.concat([result.loc[:x_start - 1], ddlv, result.loc[x_end + 1:]])


result.insert(0, "count", result.groupby(0).cumcount())
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
```

At this point, I can't wrap my head around how I would pivot the table and ensure the columns for the sub-tables are captured by individual rows in the final result.

**Desired Result:**

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Drop-Down Field Name: | Drop-Down List Name: | Drop-Down List Type: | Drop-Down List Status: | Text | Active | Default | Weight | Image |
| 1 | Test List | Test List | Specific | Active | DDL V1 | Yes | Yes | 1.00 | None |
| 2 | Test List | Test List | Specific | Active | DDL V2 | Yes | None | 2.00 | None |
| 3 | Test List | Test List | Specific | Active | DDL V3 | Yes | None | 3.00 | None |
| 4 | Test List | Test List | Specific | Active | DDL V4 | Yes | None | 4.00 | None |
| 5 | Test List | Test List | Specific | Active | DDL V5 | Yes | None | 5.00 | None |
| 6 | Test Empty List | Test Empty List | Specific | Active | None | None | None | None | None |
| 7 | Email verified? | Yes/No | Reusable | Active | Yes | Yes | None | 1.00 | green_checkmark.jpg |
| 8 | Email verified? | Yes/No | Reusable | Active | No | None | None | 0 | red_cross.jpg |
| 9 | Payment verified? | Yes/No | Reusable | Active | Yes | Yes | None | 1.00 | green_checkmark.jpg |
| 10 | Payment verified? | Yes/No | Reusable | Active | No | None | None | 0 | red_cross.jpg |
| 11 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | One | None | None | None | None |
| 12 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | Two | None | None | None | None |
| 13 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | Three | None | None | None | None |
| 14 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | Four | None | None | None | None |
| 15 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | Five | None | None | None | None |
| 16 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 1 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 17 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 2 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 18 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 3 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 19 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 4 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 20 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 5 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 21 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 6-10 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 22 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 11-15 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 23 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 15-20 | Yes | None | None | None |
| 24 | How many years expected from now? | How many years expected from now? | Specific | Active | 20+ | Yes | None | None | None |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def reorganize(gr):
    left = gr.iloc[:4, :2].set_index(0).T
    right = (
        gr.iloc[4:, 1:]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .T.set_index(0).T
    )
    # note that indexing in both frames starts from 1
    return left.join(right, how='outer')

start_marker = "Drop-Down Field Name:"
grouper = (df.iloc[:, 0] == start_marker).cumsum()

result = df.groupby(grouper).apply(reorganize).reset_index(drop=True)
result.iloc[:, :4] = result.iloc[:, :4].fillna(method='pad')
```

p.s. The code works on the assumption that columns of `df` have no specific names, i.e. they are indexed by default, starting from zero (sort of `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`)